# mktime(from php) to iphone time(string)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdate, mktime

I have in variable value from PHP function mktime(time from epoch), exacly 133123088.
How I can change it for readable date in iphone?

Is  any function to convert this format to another like NSDate or just string ?

Answer (score 1):

`NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: 133123088]`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 133123088; // NSTimeInterval is a double
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
```

Notice that `133123088` corresponds to a date in 1974. So I guess you are missing a digit in `133123088` to make it a date in 2012: For example : `1331230880`

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 1331230880;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```